# List append in recursion

Tags: python, list, recursion, append

I am unable to make a pascal triangle. I need to append to list elements in recursion, but the result of my work is list appending in list. Can u help me to do it?
My testing code is:

```
def list(row):
    if(row is 0):
        return 0
    return [row, list(row-1)]
```

If I use it, I will return list in list. I need elements in list

```
print(list(10))
```

Output:

```
[10, [9, [8, [7, [6, [5, [4, [3, [2, [1, 0]]]]]]]]]]
```

Expected output:

```
[10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

Comment: Recursion should be used.

Comment: `list` is a reserved word in python, use a different name for your function

Comment: Can you please provide an input and an expected output?

Comment: It doesn't change anything.

Comment: @Szabolcs yes sure, I have edited already

Comment: @NurislomTuraev thanks for the edit. By the way to achieve the expected result you can use: `list(range(n+1))` (`xrange` in python2). So try `list(range(10+1))`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding your specific function, here's one way you could write it

```
def foo (row):
  if row == 0:
    return [0]
  else:
    return [row] + foo (row - 1)

print(foo(10))
# [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

Perhaps a more "pythonic" way of writing that would be

```
print([10 - x for x in range (0, 11)])
# [10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

Regarding pascal's triangle, here's one way you can write the program using an auxiliary helper and continuation passing style – for those wondering, this choice was made so that the result could be assembled in a straightforward manner *and* the recursive call is in tail position, meaning this function could easily be put on a trampoline to be made stack-safe if necessary

```
def sliding (n,xs):
  if n > len(xs):
    return []
  else:
    return [xs[0:n]] + sliding(n, xs[1:])

def pascal (n):
  def aux (m, prev, k):
    if n == m:
      return k([prev])
    else:
      return aux(m + 1, [1] + [x + y for (x,y) in sliding(2, prev)] + [1], lambda rest: k([prev] + rest))
  return aux(1, [1], lambda x: x)

for line in pascal(5):
  print(line)
# [1]
# [1, 1]
# [1, 2, 1]
# [1, 3, 3, 1]
# [1, 4, 6, 4, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to concatenate the list `[x]` with the list returned as a result of calling `list(x-1)`. The nice thing about lists in python is that the `+` operator does exactly this. If we change the final return statement to `return [x] + list(x-1)` we're headed in the right direction. You'll then notice that you run into trouble when x is 0 becuase you cant add a list to an integer, so you'll want to change your base case to `return [0]`. Finally, as mentioned, it's best to avoid declaring names that overwrite python built in functions (`list` is one), so let's rename your function to `my_list`:

```
def my_list(row):
    if row == 0:
        return [0]
    return [row] + my_list(row-1)
```

This doesn't quite get you to pascal's triangle, but hopefully you're off on the right course.

Comment: Thanks. This answer is also very helpful

Answer (score 1):

What you want is probably this:

```
return [row] + list(row-1)
```

This creates a list with one element `row` and adds the other list on top of it.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a recursive range function that outputs your expected results:

```
def rec_range(n):
    return [n] + rec_range(n-1) if n else [0]
>>> rec_range(10)
[10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

Hope it helps.

Or just use `range` (`xrange` in python2.x):

```
>>> list(range(10+1))[::-1]  # reverse the list
[10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0]
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. Very helpful

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Pascal's triangle using the given  way

```
def pascal(rows):
    for i in range (rows):
    value=1
    List = [value]
    for j in range (i):
        value = value * ( i-j ) * 1 / ( j + 1 )
        List.append(int(value))
    print(List)

pascal(5)
# [1]
# [1, 1]
# [1, 2, 1]
# [1, 3, 3, 1]
# [1, 4, 6, 4, 1]
```

Comment: Recursion should be used. It is a task.